# Change cell height while scrolling a UITableView

Tags: uitableview

Is there anyway to change the height of a cell dynamically whilst scrolling a UITableView?

I need to change the height of a number of cells when the scroll position reaches a certain point as the user drags it down past the top. I can do this successfully by issuing a reloadData, however it's very abrupt since the cells just vanish.

I've also tried reloading the cells and running the begin/end updates on the table view, however in both cases the animation sends the scroll view back to the top.

I'd like to animate the cell height change without messing up the current content offset of the drag in progress.

Tim

Answer (score 0):

Use the UITableViewDelegate and implement the method

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

This solve your issue?
If it is not solving your issue, try to explain better your goal, with examples/images.

Comment: Hi. No, that doesn't answer the question at all I'm afraid. I know how to set the cell height, but I was asking how to change it dynamically, with an animation, during a scroll operation.

Comment: What should trigger the animation? Once you know how to trigger it, just update the variable you use to store the height of a particular cell, than use: `[tableView beginUpdates];`
`[tableView endUpdates];`

Comment: Hi. This is a very old question - I'm responding in case this is of interest to others. Re-reading the question the objective seems clear - as the user scrolls the table using their finger I need(ed) to change the height of certain rows based on the scroll position. I also state that I attempted to use a begin/end update block, but that that failed.

Comment: Use `motionEnded:withEvent:` or `touchesEnded:withEvent:` check if your cell is visible (if its indexPath is in the NSArray `[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]`), get the cell position and you can easily do the rest. This answer to your question?

Comment: No, I wanted to animate while the user is dragging, not once they stopped.

Comment: Just curious, were you able to accomplish it using a tableview? I wanted to implement something very similar and ended up not using a tableview, and using just a scrollview instead and adding the elements programmatically and 'saving' the height constraint of the element(s) i needed to change the height while scrolling and doing it in scrollviewdidscroll.